# how to update a checkbox value on update function on request based?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, input, checkbox

i written a very simple code to update value of checkbox but it update 1 in db on uncheck it doesnot update 0 if request is submit here is code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>If it is checked it means user can only create given customer order.</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="js-switch" name="customer_itself" @if($ot->customer_itself == 1) checked @endif>
</div>
```

controller side

```
if ($request->has('customer_itself')) {
    if($ot->customer_itself == 1){
        $ot->customer_itself = 0;
    }else{
        $ot->customer_itself = 1;
    }
```

what mistake in it?

Comment: I'm not well-versed with laravel but far as I can see and correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see the input having any value.

Comment: this is a check box when we check it then it passed value to controller that this checkbox is trigerd i am accepting that trigring using has() not value

Comment: Ok. Well see the answer below then, that looks promising.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the input type "checkbox" does not return values when unchecked.

Two solutions to choose from :

In PHP :

```
$ot->customer_itself = $request->has('customer_itself');
```

In HTML :

Force a first return to "0" to force the update of the database. This value will be overrided if the checkbox is "1" :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>If it is checked it means user can only create given customer order.</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_itself" value=0>
    <input type="checkbox" id="js-switch" name="customer_itself" @if($ot->customer_itself == 1) checked @endif>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Values of unchecked checkbox aren't pass as argument.

```
$ot->customer_itself = $request->has('customer_itself');
```

Comment: in the case of a PATCH route (laravel used in REST API), if you only want to modify one field in database, this check can be problematic